# nrpe unable to run custom perl script: Return Code: 1, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output

Tags: perl, security, nagios, dhcp, nrpe

I'm trying to implement a custom perl nagios script to check for rogue dhcp servers remotely with nrpe. On the central server when i run:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 10.9.0.25 -c check_roguedhcp
```

In my debugging logs i'm seeing this:

```
Host is asking for command 'check_roguedhcp' to be run...
Running command: sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_roguedhcp.pl  
Command completed with return code 1 and output:   
Return Code: 1, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Locally if i run the script (even as the nrpe user) I get the expected output.

On the local server my /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg has the following settings:

```
command[check_roguedhcp]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_roguedhcp.pl
command[check_dhcp]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dhcp -v
nrpe_user=nrpe
nrpe_group=nagios
```

ps aux shows nrpe is running as user nrpe (nrpe is in group nagios)

```
nrpe      5941  0.0  0.1  52804  2384 ?        Ss   08:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
```

I've added the command to /etc/sudoers

```
%nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios64/plugins/check_dhcp, /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_roguedhcp.pl
```

on my central server that does the nrpe calls, i have the following service groups and configurations:

```
define servicegroup{
       servicegroup_name       rogue_dhcp
       alias                   All dhcp monitors
}

define service{
        name                            security-service
        servicegroups                   rogue_dhcp
        register                        0
        max_check_attempts              1
}
```

Nagios can run any other check_users etc script via nrpe on this server.

Here's the perl script itself, though we know that the file executes locally just fine.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl -w  
  2 # nagios: -epn  
  3 # the above makes nagios run the script separately.  
  4 use POSIX;  
  5 use lib "/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins";  
  6 use utils qw(%ERRORS);  
  7   
  8 sub fail_usage {  
  9   if (scalar @_) {  
 10     print "$0: error: \n";  
 11     map { print "   $_\n"; } @_;  
 12   }  
 13   print "$0: Usage: \n";  
 14   print "$0 [-v [-v [-v]]]  [ []] \n";  
 15   print "$0 [-v [-v [-v]]] [-s]  [[-s]  [[-s] ]] \n";  
 16   print " \n";  
 17   exit 3 ;  
 18 }  
 19   
 20 my $verbose = 0;  
 21 my %servers=(  
 22                 "x",        "10.x.x.x",  
 23                 "x",        "10.x.x.x",  
 24                 "x",     "10.x.x.x",  
 25                 "x",      "10.x.x.x"  
 26 );  
 27   
 28 # examine commandline args  
 29 while ($ARGV=$ARGV[0]) {  
 30   my $myarg = $ARGV;   
 31   if ($ARGV eq '-s') {  
 32     shift @ARGV;  
 33     if (!($ARGV = $ARGV[0])) { fail_usage ("$myarg needs an argument"); }  
 34     if ($ARGV =~ /^-/) { fail_usage ("$myarg must be followed by an argument"); }  
 35     if (!defined($servers{$ARGV})) { $servers{$ARGV}=1; }  
 36   }  
 37   elsif ($ARGV eq '-v' ) { $verbose++; }  
 38   elsif ($ARGV eq '-h' or $ARGV eq '--help' ) { fail_usage ; }  
 39   elsif ($ARGV =~ /^-/ ) { fail_usage " invalid option ($ARGV)"; }  
 40   elsif ($ARGV =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/)  
 41 # servers should be ip addresses.  I'm not doing detailed checks for this.  
 42     { if (!defined($servers{$ARGV})) { $servers{$ARGV}=1; } }  
 43   else { last; }  
 44   shift @ARGV;  
 45 }  
 46 # for some reason I can't test for empty ARGs in the while loop  
 47 @ARGV = grep {!/^\s*$/} @ARGV;  
 48 if (scalar @ARGV) { fail_usage "didn't understand arguments: (".join (" ",@ARGV).")"; }  
 49   
 50 my $serversn = scalar keys %servers;  
 51   
 52 if ($verbose > 2) {
 53   print "verbosity=($verbose)\n";
 54   print "servers = ($serversn)\n";
 55   if ($serversn) { for my $i (keys %servers) { print "server ($i)\n"; } }
 56 }
 57 
 58 if (!$serversn) { fail_usage "no servers"; }
 59 my $responses=0;
 60 my $responders="";
 61 my @check_dhcp = qx{/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_dhcp -v};
 62 foreach my $value (@check_dhcp) {
 63   if ($value =~ /Added offer from server \@ /i){
 64     $value =~ m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/i;
 65     my $host = $1;
 66     # we find a server in our list
 67     if (defined($servers{$host})) { $responses++; $responders.="$host "; }
 68     # we find a rogue DHCP server.  Danger Will Robinson!
 69     else {
 70       print "DHCP:CRITICAL: DHCP service running on $host";
 71       exit $ERRORS{'OK'}
 72     }
 73   }
 74 }
 75 # we saw all the servers in our list.  All is good.
 76 if ($responses == $serversn) {
 77   print "DHCP:OK: $responses of $serversn Expected Responses to DHCP Broadcast";
 78   exit $ERRORS{'OK'};
 79 }
 80 # we found no DHCP responses.
 81 if ($responses == 0) {
 82   print "DHCP:OK: no rogue servers detected!!!!#!@#";
 83   exit $ERRORS{'OK'}
 84 }
 85 # we found less DHCP servers than we should have. Oh Nos!
 86 $responders =~ s/ $//;
 87 print "DHCP:OK: $responses of $serversn Responses to DHCP Broadcast. ($responders) responded. ";
 88 exit $ERRORS{'OK'};
```

Here's what I am seeing (of relevance) when I do an strace of the nrpe process.

```
 955 6950  stat("/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_roguedhcp.pl", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=2799, ...}) = 0
 956 6950  setresuid(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295) = 0
 957 6950  setresgid(4294967295, 536347864, 4294967295) = 0
 958 6950  setgroups(3, [536347864, 536347137, 536353632]) = 0
 959 6950  open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
 960 6950  socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 9)   = 3
 961 6950  fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
 962 6950  fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
 963 6950  ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff3de81ac0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
 964 6950  ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff3de81ac0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
 965 6950  ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff3de81ac0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
 966 6950  getcwd("/", 4096)                 = 2
 967 6950  sendto(3, "d\0\0\0c\4\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0cwd=\"/\" cmd=\"/us"..., 100, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12)      = 100
 968 6950  poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 500) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
 969 6950  recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\1\0\0\0&\33\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0c\4\5\0\1\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_PEEK|MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NE     TLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
 970 6950  recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\1\0\0\0&\33\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0c\4\5\0\1\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pi     d=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
 971 6950  write(2, "sudo", 4)               = 4
 972 6950  write(2, ": ", 2)                 = 2
 973 6950  write(2, "sorry, you must have a tty to ru"..., 38) = 38
 974 6950  write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
 975 6950  setresuid(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295) = 0
 976 6950  setresgid(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295) = 0
 977 6950  exit_group(1)                     = ?
 978 6949  <... read resumed> "", 4096)      = 0
 979 6949  --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
 980 6949  close(5)                          = 0
 981 6949  wait4(6950, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 6950
 970 6950  recvfrom(3, "$\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\1\0\0\0&\33\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0c\4\5\0\1\0\0\0"..., 8988, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pi     d=0, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 36
 971 6950  write(2, "sudo", 4)               = 4
 972 6950  write(2, ": ", 2)                 = 2
 973 6950  write(2, "sorry, you must have a tty to ru"..., 38) = 38
 974 6950  write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
 975 6950  setresuid(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295) = 0
 976 6950  setresgid(4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295) = 0
 977 6950  exit_group(1)                     = ?
```

Comment: You could consider `use Nagios::Plugin ;` cause this module can help you with your option handling and has some other useful stuff for creating a Nagios Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by adding the following to /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have resolved changing permissions of scripts file under /nagios/libexec/
do not work with root:root and WORK with nagios:nagios user permission!

Answer (score 0):

I changed permission of my specific script on libexec folder to allow the "Other" (non-root users) to execute it **chmod 755 myfile.pl**, and it worked well.